# Why would I see"The requested operation requires elevation" after copying an executable to network share?

Tags: windows-10, uac, smb

I have a simple .NET application that doesn't normally require admin permissions. When this executable is copied to a network share a little admin shield appears on the icon. Now, from the network share, nobody can run that executable without admin permissions.

We get "The requested operation requires elevation" or a UAC prompt when running this simple EXE from a network share.

If I copy that same file off the network on to a different computer it runs without admin privileges.

I have "Full Control" permissions on both the file and the network share in question. There are other little .NET executables that we have deployed to the same share and run them all the time. It's only happening on one particular program.

Manifest looks like this:

```
1 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION 1,0,0,0
PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,0
FILEOS 0x4
FILETYPE 0x1
{
BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
{
    BLOCK "000004b0"
    {
        VALUE "Comments", ""
        VALUE "CompanyName", "Microsoft"
        VALUE "FileDescription", "filename"
        VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.0"
        VALUE "InternalName", "filename.exe"
        VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright \xA9 Microsoft 2018"
        VALUE "LegalTrademarks", ""
        VALUE "OriginalFilename", "filename.exe"
        VALUE "ProductName", "filename"
        VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0.0.0"
        VALUE "Assembly Version", "1.0.0.0"
    }
}

BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
{
    VALUE "Translation", 0x0000 0x04B0  
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is default behavior.

To change it, you need to modify the registry.

Go to this key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters
SMB2 (if it exists, if it doesn't add DWORD SMB2=1)
change the 0 to 1 -> restart

[from here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4fd45355-3755-4ea2-b0e3-b22514becabb/cannot-run-exe-files-on-shared-drives-after-installation-of-windows-update-version-1803?forum=win10itprosecurity)

Read past the worthless MS support "did you disable AV/firewall garbage" for the answer.

***If you don't want to change windows networking to use SMB2***, I am also sure that this can be done through the group policy editor without modifying the protocol.  Windows 10 policies have changed a bit since 7 but
 [this page](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/create-an-application-whitelist-policy-in-windows/)  should get you going.

Look for the section titled "**How to whitelist specific programs using Software Restriction Policies**".  Specifically at the end of that section, you will find "Tips when creating Path Rules" that talks about UNC path whitelisting.

I hope this was what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It's not happening with every EXE file. There are 11 different executable files in this same network share folder and only one is exhibiting this behavior.

Comment: Also, this suggestion is to force SMB2 on the server side which is a terrible idea.

Comment: I have added another section to the answer @HackSlash.  I used this method for windows 7 but haven't tried it lately.  It should work.

Comment: It's not a software restriction either. Like I said: there are other EXE files in the same path that run just fine. It's just one executable. It could be the way it was compiled but the previous version didn't do this. I don't understand why it would run locally as normal user but when run from the network it wants to run elevated.

Comment: DOUGH!  Sorry @HackSlash.. I guess I should *READ* better. :^P  Have you checked the exe resource for a manifest?  It might provide a clue.

Comment: I added the manifest.